# How to compare arbitrary elements in Java PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, compare, priority-queue

I have a `PriorityQueue` that has an element with a priority. Now I want to add the same element again with a different priority and keep only the one with higher priority. I thought of checking the new element against the already present one and then deciding whether to keep the old one or replace, but I can't find a way to compare my new element against an arbitrary element from the `PriorityQueue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `PriorityQueue` was not meant to access an arbitrary element in it, it is designed to allow fast access to the head alone. If you need to do this operation frequently, probably a `java.util.TreeSet` will be a better data structure.

However, you can access any element by iterating `PriorityQueue` [using an `Iterator`] and breaking when you find your match. You cannot get performance better then `O(n)` for getting an arbitrary element in any case for a `PriorityQueue`, because it was not designed to do it.